# Is a Spring @Bean method ever called if it's not needed?

Tags: spring

Let's say I have a configuration class like so

```
@Configuration
public class NeverUsedConfig {

    @Bean
    public UselessObject getUselessObject() {
       // execute some crucial state-changing code
    }
}
```

If getUselessObject() is never called and UselessObject is never @Injected anywhere, is the getUselessObject() method ever called?

I have a similar situation, where it seems like it's being called in one environment and not in another. When it's called, I can see the logging inside the method as well as setting up some important AWS SDK Metrics. In another account/region, it doesn't seem to be called. My AWS SDK Metrics are not set up and there is no logging

Comment: There is the  `@Lazy` annotation that will load your bean lazily. This can be used on a `@Configuration`-class. Reference: [spring-lazy-annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation)

Comment: This is a good lead. I'll look for it. Maybe we have different spring configuration for one environment vs another.